# how can i put a confirmation message when the user clicks approved?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

my gridview has a approve button in every row and can approve rows when clicked, but i want to add a function where when the user clicks "Approved" there will be a messagebox or confirmation screen if the user is sure to approve the request. here is my code for the gridview, thanks in advance!

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="TransactionID" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" CellPadding="4" AllowPaging="true" PageIndex="2" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" HeaderStyle-BackColor ="CornflowerBlue" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="CornflowerBlue" Width="100%" CssClass=" table table-hover" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img style="cursor:pointer" src ="../Images/Icons/plus2.png" title="Click to expand and view item/s" />
                    <asp:Panel ID ="pnlDetails" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvDet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="ItemType" HeaderText="Type" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="250px" DataField="ItemModel" HeaderText="Model" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="140px" DataField="ItemQuantity" HeaderText="Requested Quantity" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="80px" DataField="ItemUnit" HeaderText="Unit" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="ItemDate" HeaderText="Date Needed" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-dd-MM}" HtmlEncode="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="200px" DataField="ItemDesc" HeaderText="Description" />

            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="ApproveRow" HeaderText="Approve" ItemStyle-CssClass="deleteLink" Text="Approve" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" />


        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="CornflowerBlue" />
    </asp:GridView>
             </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="RowCommand" />
         </Triggers>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a click event and then using `MessageBox.Show(...)` and then taking action based on the `DialogResult` that it returns?

Comment: messagebox does not work with asp.net

Comment: Oh, my apologies! I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: Add `OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this event?');"` this much in your `Button` html.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of ButtonField column

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Approve" CommandName="ApproveRow" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure ?')" />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply put `OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?');"` in your `Button HTML` like below:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="ApproveRow" HeaderText="Approve" ItemStyle-CssClass="deleteLink" Text="Approve" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" ItemStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this event?');" />
```